# No Login on created on tty2 to 6

Tags: terminal, login, tty, systemd

On my Debian Linux no Login is possible on terminals 2 to 6. Login on 1 works fine, xorg-session with XDM and awesome wm works, too.

The Error Message shown on these 5 screens is:

```
systemd-logind[...]: Failed to issue Method call: Launch Helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

I don't even know how to start solving this. How can I make these terminals working?

Comment: Did you search google for that error message? I get thousands of hits, that would be a good place to start debugging.